# AngularJS - Default Dropdown Select Option

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue, angular-ngmodel

This one issue is bugging me since it seems so easy to fix.

I am using plain HTML, but the data is being passed to the next view via angular.

The snippet of code looks like this:

```
<span data-ng-show="isCountry()">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-ng-model="age">
    <option value="21">21-24</option>
    <option value="25">25-30</option>
    <option value="31">31 and up</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

What I am trying to achieve:
Having `<option value="25">25-30</option>` as the default selected option when angular loads

What I've tried:

1. Having `<option value="25">25-30</option>` with a `ng-selected="age"` attribute

   `<span data-ng-show="isCountry()">
     <select class="selectpicker" data-ng-model="age">
       <option value="21">21-24</option>
       <option ng-selected="age" value="25">25-30</option>
       <option value="31">31 and up</option>
     </select>
   </span>`
2. Having `<option value="25">25-30</option>` with a `selected="selected"` attribute

   `<span data-ng-show="isCountry()">
     <select class="selectpicker" data-ng-model="age">
       <option value="21">21-24</option>
       <option selected value="25">25-30</option>
       <option value="31">31 and up</option>
     </select>
   </span>`
3. Even trying `<option value="25">25-30</option>` displayed first

   `<span data-ng-show="isCountry()">
     <select class="selectpicker" data-ng-model="age">
       <option value="25">25-30</option>
       <option value="21">21-24</option>
       <option value="31">31 and up</option>
     </select>
   </span>`

Option 2 and 3 does display the `value` I want first, but it is not passed through to the next `view`

If possible, I prefer not to touch much Angular code, as the main developer is out temporary...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a problem here, do not use 'age' as the model but try using something like 'user.age' and assign the value to it like this;

```
var user = {}; user.age = 25;
<select class="selectpicker" data-ng-model="user.age">
```

The reason it does not work in the next view is, that the 'age' is totally gone when you reassign a new value to it. Angular monitor change to a variable reference, since the variable 'age' is gone, it does not know when to update the view.  Using 'user.age' as the model, angular is watching the 'user' for changes, and if you change the age, Angular will update the view for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, After much digging into the code the - the `age` is already being set via a js function

```
a.defaultAge = {
  Country: "25"
}
```

Thanks for the help David - Your comment is a `good to know` thing for future reference.